# Problems translating a pandas dataframe from english to french using googletrans

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, translation, google-translation-api

I am using googlentrans to translate a column from a dataframe.

```py
translator = Translator()  # initalize the Translator object

data['phrase']=data['sentence'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, src='en', dest='fr').text )
```

It is supposed to work, but after I applying these 2 lines of code I am creating a column called "phrase" but is not in french. The text remains in english...

I have also used this line of code

```py
data['phrase']=data['sentence'].apply(translator.translate, src='en',dest='fr').apply(getattr,args=('text',))
```

And the problem remains the same, it seems like google trans is not applying the translation.

Best,

Comment: first select code in question and use button `{}` or shortcut `Ctrl+K` to correctly format code.

Comment: did you test function `translator.translate` on single english word ? Maybe this function doesn't work. Maybe Google closed access to Translator and now it doesn't work. Or maybe this function have daily limits and you can use only few times every day - and if you want to use more often then you have to pay for it.

Comment: in doc for [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) you can see `Due to limitations of the web version of google translate, this API does not guarantee that the library would work properly at all times (so please use this library if you don’t care about stability), **Important:** If you want to use a stable API, I highly recommend you to use [Google’s official translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs).`